# Send Email to a Gmail address from an APP Engine Application using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm working on a project which I have deployed on Google App Engine, I need to send an email when a user submits the contact form.

I have deployed my app successfully and implemented an ajax request to a PHP file, but it's not working.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Name" required="">                    
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Email ID" required="">           
             <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control input-field" placeholder="Subject" required="">                     
       </div>
       <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required=""></textarea>
       <button type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" class="btn center-block">Send message</button>
</form>
```

And Here's Javascript:
**contact.js**

```
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
    $("#contact_form input[required], #contact_form textarea[required]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color',''); 
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('background-color','#FFDEDE'); //change border color to #FFDEDE   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
            $(this).css('background-color','#FFDEDE'); //change border color to #FFDEDE   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }   
    });

    if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'subject'       : $('input[name=subject]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('https://storage.googleapis.com/www.unmundonuevo.school/php/sendmail.php', post_data, function(response){  
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<br><br><div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<br><br><div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                $("#contact_form").slideUp(); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

And Here's my **sendmail.php:**

```
use \google\appengine\api\mail\Message;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
        $email = 'arycloud7@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'A Test Subject';
        $mailBody = 'This is a test body.';
        $message = new Message();
        $message->setSender("abdul12391@gmail.com");
        $message->addTo($email);
        $message->setSubject($subject);
        $message->setTextBody($mailBody);
        $message->send();

        header("Location: /mail_sent");

    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {

        $error = "Unable to send mail. $e";
    }
}
```

When I submit the contact form it returns an error as:
In the browser's console some errors display as:

> [Error] Origin http://www.unmundonuevo.school is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://unnuevomundo-contact.appspot.com/sendmail.php due to access control checks.
>   [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://www.unmundonuevo.school is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (sendmail.php, line 0)

What mean by these errors?

What's there can be wrong?

Hlep me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin)(or CORS).

You can do it by writing a configuration file and applying it to the bucket like below:

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://example
```

cors-json-file.json:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://example.appspot.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

You can get more information in [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors).